# Get JSON data where value is nearest to number X

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a user inputted number, X. Along with a list of data in JSON format.

```
**114**  80  145     175     240     320
**123**  85  155     190     260     345
**132**  90  170     205     280     370
```

I would like to match X with the nearest number in the first column and then return the following values in that row.

Not sure if I have formatted the JSON in the best way. But here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/wuSux/

Comment: How do you define nearest?  I would suggest you check out the lodash.com or underscore.org libraries.. They have plenty of methods to sort, group, and find values.

Comment: Is it possible to have that JSON data pre-sorted by the values of the first column? This would enable you to do binary search, which would be most efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var data = [{"Body Weight":114," Untrained": 80," Novice": 145," Intermediate": 175," Advanced": 240," Elite": 320},
            {"Body Weight":123," Untrained": 85," Novice": 155," Intermediate": 190," Advanced": 260," Elite": 345},
            {"Body Weight":132," Untrained": 90," Novice": 170," Intermediate": 205," Advanced": 280," Elite": 370}];

var x = 140,
    difference = 0,
    bestIndex = 0,
    bestDifference = Infinity,
    i, cur, bodyWeight;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cur = data[i];
    bodyWeight = cur["Body Weight"];
    difference = Math.abs(x - bodyWeight);
    if (difference < bestDifference) {
        bestDifference = difference;
        bestIndex = i;
    }
}

console.log(data[bestIndex]);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wuSux/2/

Change the value of `x` to find the closest to that number.

Comment: Excellent, does exactly what I want. Thanks Ian.

Comment: Is there any way I can request the 'Untrained', 'Novice', etc. values from `data[bestIndex]`?

Comment: @Chris Absolutely! Just use `data[bestIndex].Untrained` or `data[bestIndex].Novice`, etc.

Comment: I am getting 'undefined' when I try that on jsfiddle, any ideas?

Comment: @Chris I apologize, I didn't realize the keys in the objects have a space at the beginning. You'll have to use `data[bestIndex][" Untrained"]`, but I'd suggest removing the spaces if possible. http://jsfiddle.net/wuSux/3/

Answer (score 2):

Change your data so the last `Body Weight` is `320` instead of `"320+"`, then:

```
function getClosest(x) {
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (x > data[i]["Body Weight"]) break
    }
    if (i === data.length - 1) return data[i];
    if (i === -1) return data[0];

    return data[i + +(x > ((data[i]["Body Weight"] + data[i + 1]["Body Weight"]) / 2))];
}
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/s8Xge/

---

Or if you prefer:

```
function getClosest(x) {
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        if (x > data[i]["Body Weight"]) break
    }
    return i === data.length - 1                                     ? data[i] :
           i === -1                                                  ? data[0] :
           (data[i]["Body Weight"] + data[i + 1]["Body Weight"]) / 2 ? data[i + 1] :
                                                                       data[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks yowza. This helps me get the nearest 'Body Weight', however I'm after the other values, too. (Sorry if I wasn't clear enough)

Comment: @Chris: This returns the entire object. I just grabbed the `"Body Weight"` property to display in the alert.