# Return object in array based on a range

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects.

```
var array = [{"First object", 15}, {"Second object", 20}];
```

I have made an object constructors function so the names of the values are `title` and `height`.

How can I make a function that returns a value if in range between the height value for each array. Let's say if I call `currentObject(17)` I want to return the second object. If I call `currentObject(10)` I want the first object in this array in return.

```
var array = [{"First object", 15}, {"Second object", 20}];

function currentObject(height) {
  // return object that is between the smallest closest number to height 
  // and the height-value of the object before it.
}
```

I've tried several options with `.filter` and `.find`, but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it yet. I thought about adding `startHeight` and `endHeight` in the array, but I thought that would be a lot of redundant data as the ranges starts from the previous object.

Comment: So you want to find the object in the array with height closest to, but not exceeding the height you input into that function?

Comment: @ldtcoop Yes, that's correct. I found ways to get the object if I use the specific number with .filter. But like you say, I want the second object in return if I send 16,17,18,19 or 20 as arguments.

Comment: One more question: Is the array always going to be sorted?

Comment: Yeah. I will add extra objects manually, so the height will always be increasing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16223510/10634638

Answer (score 1):

What you want is reduce

```
const currentObject = (height, data) => data.reduce((result, current) => Math.abs(result.height - height) > Math.abs(current.height - height) ? current : result);
```

This will iterate through the data array with each loop replacing the accumulator if it is closer to height. Your final accumulator will be the result closest to height.

Comment: it is a parameter to the function, call it with currentObject(height, array)

Comment: I tried it with my code, but something seem to be wrong with it. Cause it returns the first object when height starting at 18 and the second one when height starting at 33.

Comment: Post your test data